# Do I actually need to reconfigure *everything* to use a tiling windows manager?

Tags: gnome, window-manager

I'm new to Linux and I decided to try a tiling windows manager. I've installed BSPWM because I like it quadtree-like structure. I've logged out and logged in selecting BSPWM. I've learned how to launch programs and navigate between windows. That worked quite well and I'm pretty happy about BSPWM as a window manager. Problem is: **what about everything else?** It seems that all Gnome configs stopped working and I've been having a lot of work to restore them one by one. For example:

- Mouse speed: had to restore with a `xinput` command on `bspwmrc`
- Keyboard refresh rate: had to restore with a `xset` command on `bspwmrc`
- Touchpad configs: had to restore making a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.ds/90-trackpad.conf` file
- Night Light: had to restore installing redshift and running on `bspwmrc`
- Keyboard tweaks: had to restore with `setxkbmap` on `bspwmrc`
- Background image: had to restore with `feh` on `bspwmrc`
- Volume and Brighness controls on function keys: still not working
- Closing lids logs out: still not working
- Wifi: still don't know how to connect without Gnome's UI.

And so on. At this point, I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Do I actually need to manually "build" each of the things that Gnome does automatically, or is there some general config utility that works with BSPWM and similar and I'm just not aware? Why can't I just use BSPWM as the *window manager* of Gnome, without destroying all the rest?

Comment: "Why can't I just use BSPWM as the window manager of Gnome" GNOME simply doesn't support that. GNOME Shell (and supported variants like Flashback) is the One True Shell™, and the Mutter component of GNOME Shell is the One True Window Manager™. XFCE or LXDE with  BSPWM as a window manager might be more friendly, though.

Comment: Using MATE DE with [X-tile](https://www.giuspen.com/x-tile/) may be an option too.

Answer (score 2):

Tiling window managers are just that: **window managers**. It are not desktop environments. Therefore, if you run a window manager (e.g. "openbox" as a floating window manager, "i3" or BSPWM as tiling window managers), and not a full desktop environment (e.g. xfce, Gnome Shell, KDE, LXQT, ...), you have to set up everything yourself. Tedious at first, but many advanced users consider it fun, and it *the* way to make a system that truly is yours, and behaves as you tell it to do in every respect.

> Do I actually need to reconfigure *everything* to use a tiling windows manager?

Yes. :-)

Some distributions ship with a fully configured setup centered around a tiling window manager. **Regolith** is an Ubuntu derivative that builds a preconfigures desktop environment around `i3` window manager and Gnome tools. **Manjaro** has a preconfigured i3 spin. However, the offer is quite limited, specially because these people that tend to want to run only a window manager are also these that want to set up their entire system themselves.

Specifically for Gnome Shell: no, you cannot use any different window manager. Gnome Shell is quite locked-in in that respect, and uses its own window manager `mutter`. However, you could use a tiling window manager in other desktops, notably XFCE.